# Answer ComplexInfinity for a clearly convergent integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to compute the following integral:

```
Integrate[-(λ/π) (1 - (wn - w)^2 / Ω0^2 Log[1 + Ω0^2/(wn - w)^2] + 
            Ω0^2/(2 (wn + w)^2)) ϕ/(w^2 + ρ^2), 
  {w, Ω, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {λ > 0, wn > 0, Ω0 > 0, ϕ > 0, ρ > 0, Ω > wn}]
```

$$
- \int \limits_\Omega^\infty \mathrm{d} \omega \frac{\lambda}{\pi} \left[ 1 - \frac{(\omega_n - \omega)^2}{\Omega_0^2} \log \left( 1 + \frac{\Omega_0^2}{(\omega_n - \omega)^2} \right)  + \frac{\Omega_0^2}{2 (\omega_n + \omega)^2} \right] \frac{\phi}{\omega^2 + \rho^2}
$$

The answer, after several minutes, is `ComplexInfinity`. Why is that so? The first function in the bracket (1-...log(...)) is very similar to a Lorentzian with width `Omega0`, it's asymptotics is `1/w^2`. The second function is just asymptotic version of the first, while `wn, Omega >> Omega0` taking into an account. Last part is just multiplicative Lorentzian factor with a width rho, which is positive (in assumptions). So this function is 1) bounded 2) asymptotic o(1/w^4). Why is the answer `ComplexInfinity`?

Bonus: is this integral doable analytically? If yes, how do I force *Mathematica* to show the result? If not, what should I do to get answer when I'm interested in this setup: `0 < wn < Omega`, `Omega >> Omega0`, that log part is actually quite important, as the integral goes through full shape of the function (remember, 0 < wn < Omega, so integral catches all details of that function)

Bonus2: someone edited one of my previous questions so that symbols like π, etc appeared as they should: `π`. How did he do that? :O

Comment: Do you have good reason to believe that this integral can be done analytically?  If not, then set values for your parameters and try `NIntegrate` instead.

Comment: I need it analytically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mathematica* knows how to do the indefinite integral analytically.

```
indefInt = Integrate[-(λ/π) (1 - (wn - w)^2 / Ω0^2 Log[1 + Ω0^2/(wn - w)^2] + 
        Ω0^2/(2 (wn + w)^2)) ϕ/(w^2 + ρ^2)]
```

Then you can take the result, and insert the limits following the fundamental theorem.

But, *Mathematica* fails to produce a finite upper limit with `Limit[indefInt, w->∞]`.  Therefore, use

```
ser = Normal[Series[indefInt, {w, ∞, 0}]]
```

and take the leading term.

Unfortunately, the leading term still contains `Log[1/w]`, and `(Log[1/w])^2`.  In this case, you need take the limit more carefully.

Apply the transformation `Log[1/w] -> -L`, and construct the series for large `L`:

```
ser2 = Series[ser/.Log[1/w] -> -L, {L, ∞, 0}]
```

Unfortunately, the output is of the form $(\text{stuff})L + (\text{const}) + \mathcal{O}(L^{-1})$.  Fortunately, however, the $(\text{stuff})$ vanishes under your conditions, so the limiting value is given by $(\text{const})$, which you can extract by copy and pasting from output of `Series`:

```
upperlimit = 1/(2 π) λ ϕ * (-((π (2 wn^4 + 2 ρ^4 - ρ^2 Ω0^2 + wn^2 (4 ρ^2 + Ω0^2)))/(2 ρ (wn^2 + ρ^2)^2)) + 1/Ω0^2 (-((I (wn - I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn - I ρ]^2 + 12 Log[wn - I ρ] Log[-(1/(-wn + I ρ))] + 12 Log[-(1/(-wn + I ρ))]^2))/(3 ρ)) + (I (wn + I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn + I ρ]^2))/(3 ρ) + (I (wn - I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn - I (ρ - Ω0)]^2 + 12 Log[wn - I (ρ - Ω0)] Log[-(1/(-wn + I (ρ - Ω0)))] + 12 Log[-(1/(-wn + I (ρ - Ω0)))]^2))/(6 ρ) - (I (wn + I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn + I (ρ - Ω0)]^2))/(6 ρ) + (I (wn - I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn - I (ρ + Ω0)]^2 + 12 Log[wn - I (ρ + Ω0)] Log[-(1/(-wn + I (ρ + Ω0)))] + 12 Log[-(1/(-wn + I (ρ + Ω0)))]^2))/(6 ρ) - (I (wn + I ρ)^2 (π^2 + 3 Log[wn + I (ρ + Ω0)]^2))/(6 ρ)))
```

The lower limit is just `lowerlimit = indefInt/.w->Ω`.  And so the value of your definite integral is

```
upperlimit - lowerlimit
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is nice. When I run Simplify with my assumptions on (stuff), I get zero. Which is nice, but when I run Simplify for just Floor[Arg[-wn/(wn-i rho)]/2pi], I don't get -1 as expected, but I get Cases. That's why I am confused that Mathematica Simplifies that horrible (stuff) to zero right away. Thank you, although quite messy, it gets job done in a clear, feasible way!